# Supremum and infimum of $\frac{x}{\sin x}$ on $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

What is the *supremum* and *infimum* of $\frac{x}{\sin(x)}$ on the interval $[0,\frac{ \pi}{2}]$?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know the definition of supremum and infimum? If you do not, have a look at your lecture notes or book etc.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{x}{\sin(x)}$ is increasing on the given interval.

Comment: Downvoted as you gave no further context other than the question itself. Exempli gratia: what have you tried with so far?

Comment: Do you mean the interval $(0,\pi/2]$? The expression is undefined at $x=0$

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{x}{\sin x}$ is positive, increasing and log-convex on $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. It follows that the minimum of the given function is attained at $x=0$ (where I guess $\frac{x}{\sin x}$ is defined as $1$, removing the removable discontinuity) and the maximum is attained at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

**Proof**. By letting $g(x)=\log(x)-\log(\sin x)$ we have $g'(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{\tan x}\geq 0$ (since $\tan x\geq x$) and $g''(x)=\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}-\frac{1}{x^2}\geq 0$ (since $\sin x \leq x$).